Remove duplicates based on date relation
I am conducting a study on urine infections. Each row is a urine culture result. Patients will have a hospital number. Some of them may submit multiple urine samples throughout the study and therefore there will be duplicates of hospital numbers. I have the submission dates of the samples.
What I want to do is to keep only certain results.
I would ideally like to keep only the first result from within a 1 week time span (inclusive) for the same hospital number. Please also outline how i could change it to 2 weeks, 1 month etc.
In my actual data set the matching hospital numbers are not currently next to each other and will be separated by many other results.
Thanks
Dataframe <- data.frame(date = c("01.01.2024", "02.01.2024", "12.01.2024", "13.01.2024", "20.01.2024", "24.01.2024"),
                    Hopital_number=c(123, 123, 345, 345, 345, 678),
                    Whatiwant=c("Keep", "Remove", "Keep", "Remove", "Keep", "Keep"))



So you are not allowed to sort rows in the dataset?

I mean I could sort rows yes if it made a difference. Just its not currently sorted that way

df$date <- dmy(df$date)

Filter data for 1 week windows;
filtered_data <- df %>%
  group_by(Hospital_number) %>%
  filter(row_number(date) == 1 | 
  date - lag(date) > days(7)) %>%
  ungroup()

for week 2, change "lag(date) > days(14)
Similarly for month based.
Let me know if this solves the problem.

You're a hero, will check if that works. Appreciate the effort.

Maybe something like this could kind of work. There must be better ways to do this.
General idea: for each row that we want to keep, I define a "time window" (from the date of the row to 7 days later) in variables window_start and window_end. 
For the first date (within each hospital) things are easy: the window starts at the date and it ends after 7 days. 
For the next row, if the date is later than window_end then we reset a new window starting from this new date and lasting for 7 days. Instead, if the date is earlier than window_end, then we will want to delete this row, and we want to keep the previous window as ongoing for the subsequent row.
To do all of this, I sort the data by date within each hospital id.
Dataframe <- data.frame(date = c("01.01.2024", "02.01.2024", "12.01.2024", "13.01.2024", "20.01.2024", "24.01.2024"),
                        Hopital_number=c(123, 123, 345, 345, 345, 678),
                        Whatiwant=c("Keep", "Remove", "Keep", "Remove", "Keep", "Keep"))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Dataframe$date <- dmy(Dataframe$date) # transform date in Date format

days <- 7 # time window set to 7 days, it can be changed

df2 <- Dataframe %>%
  group_by(Hopital_number) %>%        # group by id
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% # sort by date within each hospital id
  mutate(window_start = as.Date(ifelse(row_number()== 1, date, NA)),    #initial window_start for the first row (in each id)
         window_end = as.Date(ifelse(row_number()== 1, date+days, NA))) #initial window_end for the first row (in each id)



for (i in 1:ncol(df2)) {
  if (is.na(df2$window_start[i])) {
   if (df2$date[i] > df2$window_end[i-1]) {
    df2$window_start[i] = df2$date[i]
    df2$window_end[i] = df2$date[i]+days
  } else {
    df2$window_start[i] = df2$window_start[i-1]
    df2$window_end[i] = df2$window_end[i-1]
  }
  }
}

df2 %>%
  filter(date == window_start)%>%
  distinct( date, Hopital_number) # if there is more than one row on the same date for each hospital

# A tibble: 4 × 2
# Groups:   Hopital_number [3]
  date       Hopital_number
  <date>              <dbl>
1 2024-01-01            123
2 2024-01-12            345
3 2024-01-20            345
4 2024-01-24            678


A base R version to try
Dataframe$date = as.Date(Dataframe$date, "%d.%m.%Y")
Dataframe = sort_by(Dataframe, ~date) # might be not needed
Dataframe$wn = strftime(Dataframe$date, format = "%V-%Y")
Dataframe[!duplicated(Dataframe[, c("Hopital_number", "wn")]), ]

        date Hopital_number Whatiwant      wn
1 2024-01-01            123      Keep 01-2024
3 2024-01-12            345      Keep 02-2024
5 2024-01-20            345      Keep 03-2024
6 2024-01-24            678      Keep 04-2024

Should be fast. A re-write as piped version is possible.

You could create a week variable using format then filter on that. Below, using %U in format will give you the week number (0-53), but I also added the year in case your data span over several years.
Dataframe %>%
  #skip if real data in date format already
  mutate(date = lubridate::parse_date_time(date, orders = "dmy")) %>% 
  # Create week variable then filter
  mutate(week = format(date, "%Y-%U")) %>%
  filter(date == first(date),
         .by = c(Hopital_number, week))

Output:
        date Hopital_number Whatiwant    week
1 2024-01-01            123      Keep 2024-00
2 2024-01-12            345      Keep 2024-01
3 2024-01-20            345      Keep 2024-02
4 2024-01-24            678      Keep 2024-03

Note you can add ... %>% select(-week) if you want to drop the week variable.
